# How to schedule the class for every one minute in salesforce?

Tags: schedulebatch

To schedule class for every one min i tried this one but it schedule after 1 hr. Is my Cron expression is correct or i did some other mistake...??

```
global class MorningMailSchedule1 implements Schedulable{
   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        PendingTaskBatch pending = new PendingTaskBatch(); //ur batch class
        database.executebatch(pending,200);
    }
    Public static void SchedulerMethod() {
    string timeinterval = '0 1 * * * ? *';
    System.schedule('BatchApexDemo-Every1mins',timeinterval, new MorningMailSchedule1());
  }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lowest possible iteration is 1 hour, that being said, you have to add multiple schedules for every minute.

```
System.schedule('MorningMailSchedule1 Job 1', '0 0 * * * ?', new MorningMailSchedule1 ());
System.schedule('MorningMailSchedule1 Job 2', '0 1 * * * ?', new MorningMailSchedule1 ());
System.schedule('MorningMailSchedule1 Job 3', '0 2 * * * ?', new MorningMailSchedule1 ());
System.schedule('MorningMailSchedule1 Job 4', '0 3 * * * ?', new MorningMailSchedule1());

.

.

.
System.schedule('MorningMailSchedule1 Job 60', '0 59 * * * ?', new MorningMailSchedule1());
```

That being said, it's not guaranteed that scheduler will run at the time you specified. I have seen a job scheduled for 9 am running at 11am.  It depends on resources salesforce has at that given point.

Also you can have at max 5 batches/Job running at same time, thus 90% of your batches will move to flex queue for holding. Scheduling job every minute looks like an Overkill on SF.

Is there a better way to handle this?

I would suggest instead of using a scheduler directly use batch.

in finish method of a batch, call the same batch again. Thus in your case,

Batch class code.

```
public class PendingTaskBatch implements DataBase.Batchable{

     //Start

      //Execute code

    public void finish(BatchableContext bc){
       PendingTaskBatch pending = new PendingTaskBatch(); //ur batch class
       Database.executebatch(pending,200);
    }

}
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005Ih3IAE

Comment: Here is the shortest code to schedule apex batch every minutes using forloop in salesforce. See Aman Gupta 161's Reply : 
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000ISsPQAW
Mark this answer useful if it helped you.